# MIGRATING MySQL to oracle database with error

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to migrate MySQL database to oracle using SQL developer has following error ORA-1400 -cannot insert null in rep:MD_PROJECT,id

Comment: after creating migration repository it has create d table md_project has id column not null column constaints

Comment: Since we have no way of checking the tables, you should just re-check your query in order to not try inserting a NULL value into a NOT NULL column.

Comment: how to check query??

Comment: MD_PROJECT is ID is automatically created after creation of repository.

Comment: Well then you should ignore all null value records whilst migrating, afaik there's no other way, perhaps someone else might get a brighter idea.

Comment: its giving me error.it not procceding further